# How to limit resources for specific roles Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I am currently setting up a cluster for a team. I've setup a hierarchial role based authentication. I've used the Kuberentes role API to define the roles. However, you can only restrict the CRUD operations for the roles.

How can I limit resources like cpu or memory based on roles?

EDIT:
Seems like there is no way to do that directly. Namespaces would have to be created for each role and then ResourceQuotas will have to be applied on them.

Comment: you can put quotas on namespace, not on role. So you have to create separate namespaces for separate teams, there is no other way in Kubernetes.

Comment: I see. In that case, what is the recommended way to have role based access to the resources? Creating different namespaces for the different roles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to use Resource Quotas Policy in Kubernetes.

Refer to this link - [Resource Quotes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)

Comment: Resource quotas restrict access to an entire namespace. So, I would need to create a namespace for each role and then apply resource quotas for them. This does the solve the problem indirectly, but I'm looking for a direct solution.

Answer (score 0):

Create different namespace for each team. you should be using ResourceQuota to limit the resources at namepsace level.

Follow the link for help --> [ResourceQuota in Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/policy/resource-quotas/)